# EF Core, one to many relationships, multiple tables with single foreign table

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core, .net-5, ef-core-5.0

In attempt to reduce the number of tables in a database, I'd like to use a single table to store the same type of data for multiple reference tables: a one to many relationship several times over with a single foreign table.

```
public class Note
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public int TargetId { get; set; }
    public TargetType TargetType { get; set; }
}

public enum TargetType
{
    Article,
    Order,
    Task,
    Ticket
}

public class Article
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Order
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Task
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}

public class Ticket
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public ICollection<Note> Notes { get; set; }
}
```

Using Code First, I've attempted OnModelCreating:

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Transfer>().HasMany(x =>
    x.LineItems.Where(y => y.TargetId == x.Id && y.TargetType == LineItemTarget.Transfer)).WithOne();
```

This produces:

> System.ArgumentException: 'The expression 'x => x.Notes.Where(y => ((y.TargetId == x.Id) AndAlso (Convert(y.TargetType, Int32) == 1)))' is not a valid member access expression. The expression should represent a simple property or field access: 't => t.MyProperty'. (Parameter 'memberAccessExpression')'

At the time of the query, I've attempted essentially the same approach:

```
return await _dbContext.Transfers.Include(x => x.LineItems.Where(y => y.TargetId == x.Id))
    .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

Which produces:

> ```
> System.InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression 'DbSet<Note>()
>    .Where(l => EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(EntityShaperExpression: 
>        EntityType: Article
>        ValueBufferExpression: 
>            ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
>        IsNullable: False
>    , "Id") != null && object.Equals(
>        objA: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(EntityShaperExpression: 
>            EntityType: Article
>            ValueBufferExpression: 
>                ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember
>            IsNullable: False
>        , "Id"), 
>        objB: (object)EF.Property<Nullable<int>>(l, "ArticleId")))
>    .Where(l => l.TargetId == x.Id && (int)l.TargetType == 3)'
> ```
>
> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to 'AsEnumerable', 'AsAsyncEnumerable', 'ToList', or 'ToListAsync'. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

I understand this method is recommending I bring the results back to the application and attempt to filter further application side as it's unable to automatically map the relationship because "ArticleId" doesn't exist on Note.

I have also attempted to use Query Filters which I quickly learned is the same tactic as the previous option, simply applied to all queries on that table. The last thing I am currently aware of is using raw SQL which I cannot seem to map to the Note objects and would greatly prefer to avoid raw SQL altogether.

Essentially I am attempting to write this SQL query in LINQ, using Articles and TargetType.Article, then the same for Order, Task, Ticket, and any other tables:

```
SELECT * FROM Articles JOIN Notes ON Articles.Id = Notes.TargetId AND Notes.TargetType = 1
```

How does one perform that query on the database using LINQ?

Comment: I think your first problem is because you’re using an enum type for targettype. I know you’re trying to reduce your tables but in this case you may have to have a targettype class with your Id and values to create the table and link to it on notes.

Comment: *"In attempt to reduce the number of tables in a database"* Why? Database tables, especially with the help of ORM using base classes to represent the common fields and migrations has no cost. Non standard designs do. This type of "logical" relationship (search for the term "polymorphic association") is not supported by EF because it is not supported by relational databases - the only supported relationship is via FK, which can reference *single* table primary/unique key. That's it. You can create such database, but you can't use navigation properties ...

Comment: ... and must code all queries and operations (including insert/update/delete + deleting the "parent") manually (for queries - plain LINQ with manual joins, no `Include` or similar sugar because they work with navigation properties which you can't have) etc. It just doesn't worth.